# Tulsi mala rules before wearing around neck

Tags: tulasi

Hello everyone please help me.
I bought a tulsi mala to wear around my neck.
I chant ramanama(No mantras).
I read that we have to offer tulsi mala to bhagwan vishnu before wearing it around our neck.
I read that we have to offer it first in vishnu temple and wash it in pachagavya after that.
Can anyone tell the procedure in detail?
Can i remove old mala after wearing new one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can remove the old tulsi mala and offer it to ganga or any river.